What kind of neural network can extract brand, subbrand, sku, percents, weight, type, taste as separate words from product titles?
I have a task to make product titles atomizer.
For example: "Cheese BellaVitano Soft 30% 450g" ->
Product category: dairy products
Product type: cheese
Product subtype: soft
Brand: BellaVitano
Percents: 30%
Weight: 450g
The titles could be made from words reductions like: "Ch. BVit s. 30% 450g"
Titles could have tastes like "apple, orange", etc.
Title could be larger, contain different properties in different order.
I have a list of all possible values for each category (all possible brands, all possible tastes, all possible categories, etc.). For numeric values it is harder, since it could be anything.
I don't understand what kind of neural network can handle it. What it's input and what it's output.
